# how to implement network for real time game

Tags: android, networking, time

I'm building a new Android game, it is intended to be real time multiplayer, similar to clash of clans but real time and synchronous battles. 
Which tools or algorithms used Imperium (FX game) to implement those real time battles? There isn't any lag and there is a lot of info to transfer between clients, for example the life and coordinates of 2000 soldiers, the damage they are do or receive (it is random) and so on..

I was thinking on make a listener somewhere on a server, then delegate the "server job" to one of the clients, and this one should be updating itself and the other client but, is it going to be fast enough not to notice lag if the connection is made with sockets?

Comment: They are always sending datas' delta (only changes) encoded in binary, so it can, additionally it is not happening 60/s but at much much lower rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some libraries so if any1 had the same question they can research here:

https://nextpeer.atlassian.net/wiki/display/NS/Android+Advanced+Integration+Guide
http://swarmconnect.com/admin/docs/libgdx

[Synchronizing game sprites over network in XNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771951/synchronizing-game-sprites-over-network-in-xna)